# Spatial Correlation in R with rasters

Tags: r, maps, correlation, raster

I would like to create a spatial correlation to see how local precipitation amounts correlate with annual precipitation over a specified yearly period. I would like the result to be a raster layer that shows how well the surrounding area correlates with the specific point. I have attached an image below showing the precipitation correlation surrounding Akcakale over the 1910-2019 period, where a correlation of <3 and >-3 is not shown.

Is there a way to do this on R using the raster package?

[image: Precipitation correlation of Akcakale from 1910-2019]

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck? if so, what is your error message? do you have some sample data to share?

Comment: I have tried using the spatialEco and raster packages, and the rasterCorrelation command. But rasterCorrelation only seems to work for two rasters. I have one for every year from 1910-2019. Additionally, I need to isolate the correlation to a specific area fo the raster.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have figured something out. This code requires a location to be given as a SpatialPointsDataFrame (using sp) and a blank raster (tempraster) for the results to go in. var_stack is a raster stack of the variables of interest. In this case, I used monthly precipitation values available from CHELSA. This will return a raster file that shows the spatial correlation with the location provided.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)


# Load rasters
files <- list.files(pattern = "pr_", full.names = T)
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  temp <- raster(files[i])
  if(i == 1) precip_stack <- stack(temp)
  if(i ! = 1) precip_stack <- addLayer(precip_stack,temp)
 }

# Create tempraster
resolution <- res(precip_stack)
tempraster <- raster(
  nrows = ny, ncols = nx,
  crs = '+init=EPSG:4326',
  xmn = -180, xmx = 180,
  ymn = -90, ymx = 90,
  res = c(resolution,resolution)
)

#Create location. An example. For SPDFs, lon before lat.

location <- as.data.frame(cbind("Reigate", -0.20651382829652656, 
51.237555987546344))

location$V2 <- as.numeric(location$V2)
location$V3 <- as.numeric(location$V3)

location <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(location[2:3], location)

SpatialCorr <- function(location,var_stack,tempraster){
  loc_extract <- raster::extract(var_stack,location, df =T)
  loc_extract <- t(loc_extract)
  loc_extract <- loc_extract[-1,]

  lay_vars <- var_stack[]

  for(i in 1:nrow(lay_vars)){
    temp <- lay_vars[i,]

    if(is.na(temp)==F){
      res <- cor(loc_extract,temp)
    }

    if(is.na(temp)==T) res <- NA

    if(i == 1) Output <- res
    if(i != 1) Output <- rbind(Output,res)
  }

  tempraster[] <- Output
  result <- tempraster
  return(result)
}

Reigate_pr_cor <- SpatialCorr(location,precip_stack,tempraster)
plot(Reigate_pr_cor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
library(terra)
library(geodata)
w <- geodata::worldclim_country("Belgium", "prec", ".")
pt <- cbind(5, 51)
```

Solution

```
loc <- extract(w, pt) |> unlist()
x <- app(w, \(i) cor(i, loc))
```

And a map

```
plot(x)
points(pt)
```

[image]